# slick.js and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Hello I'm trying to get [slick.min.js](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/) to work in IE8, but I'm getting an error:

> Error: 'jquery is undefined' (Line 18 character 27)

I'm using slick.min.js 1.3.15. Same result as slick.min.js 1.3.11.

And have these in my head section

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Aon Hewitt Cloud Solutions</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/human-capital-consulting/talent/cloud-solutions/bin/js/slick.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or provide a link?

Comment: If you're using jQuery 1.7, why use jQuery Migrate? Also, you should place your `x-ua-compatible` meta tag *first* inside the `<head>`. Can you confirm in the Network tab of the Developer Tools that jQuery and jQuery Migrate are even loading?

Comment: before of writer code with slick, you try write some simple such as $(document).on('ready', function(){ alert('ie load jquery') });